# What's the `_` meaning in nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx

what's the `_` meaning in nginx?

in a nginx.conf I see this config:

```
listen       8080;
server_name  _;
```

what's the `_` meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names):

> There is nothing special about this name, it is just one of a myriad
> of invalid domain names which never intersect with any real name.
> Other invalid names like “--” and “!@#” may equally be used.

With current versions of Nginx, it is perfectly valid to remove the `server_name` directive from the `server` block, rather than specify it with a fake name.